# Book: Two kids get powers where one is so fast that time seems to slow down around him while other can control time itself

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel, time

In this book two kids got powers (believe the setting was back in medieval times where this took place in a village), where one kid can perceive everything as almost non-moving due to his speed, while the other can control time itself (pretty sure he could cause time to fold on itself).

There was a scene in the book where it showed the perspective of a man on a spaceship who was one of the various iterations of a timefold, but he ended up not being the last iteration of himself and instead being one of the one's who didn't reach his destination and was trapped.

Pretty sure there was also a scene involving a waterfall, but it's been like 5 years. I remember this book was extremely heavy into explaining the depths of time travel like the scene with the space ship, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I believe I read a few chapters of that book.
The protagonist is a boy who has been learning from his father but

> one day his father "dies" (the boy doesn't actually see the father dead, only hears him saying something along the lines of don't come here, I don't want you see me die, but I'm going to die because a tree has fallen on top of me).

Well, in the story, the people are living in a planet that was once colonised by people from Earth but they have regressed to the medieval age.
Everybody has some kind of power.
The main character was somehow able to see the paths that other people took years and even centuries ago.
Some time after

> the father died

, he finds a pair of kids/brothers playing near the edge of a waterfall and one slips and ends up hanging from a rock, and the main character tries to help him, but in that exact spot some other man slipped and ended hanging from the same rock.
The brother who is not hanging has the ability to slow down time, and he does so ¿to try to do something? (I think he's just dumb) However when the time goes slower, the main character begins to be able to interact with the people of the past and he's not able to interact with the kid hanging, but with the person-from-the-past. And in the end

> the person from the past is able to recover, while the kid of the present falls and dies.

When the two boys (the main character and the brother who has time powers) go back to the brothers' village, they find that their incident with the time deceleration + interaction with the past, has changed the present, introducing a new religion.

I didn't read more than when the two boys got to see a merchant to exchange some gems for money to pay the couple that let the boys spend the night in their inn.

All in all, I think it has poor character development and I didn't like the setting.

The book's name is [Pathfinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pathfinder_series), by Orson Scott Card.

Also, I got the PDF of the book here:

https://blindhypnosis.com/pathfinder-pdf-orson-scott-card.html

Watch out for the minefield of viruses and adds in those webpages.

Comment: epic thanks a lot, sorry for the late reply lol